# Java Stream: group by three fields and collect the last one

Tags: java, collections, stream, java-stream, collectors

my object type is:

```
public class MyObjectDTO {
    Long id;
    String name;
    LocalDate date;
    String property;
}
```

I have an ArrayList of this object with this data:

```
Element0: 1 name1 2018-01-01 property1
Element1: 1 name1 2018-01-01 property2
Element2: 2 name2 2015-05-05 property77
Element3: 2 name2 2015-05-05 property88
Element4: 2 name2 2015-05-05 null
Element5: 3 name3 2020-12-31 property99
```

I would like to have a new `ArrayList<MyObjectDTO>` grouped like this:

```
Element0: 1 name1 2018-01-01 property1, property2
Element1: 2 name2 2015-05-05 property77, property88, null
Element2: 3 name3 2020-12-31 property99
```

So, I would like to group by id, name and data, and I would like to collect the `String property` in one `String`.

Is it possible to do with Java Stream?

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Comment: The short answer is "Yes". Perhaps you should try a few things yourself, and update your post if you run into specific problems.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul tried by myself :-) but maybe I don't know the right stream sintax

Comment: As general guidance for SO, you should include your latest compiling attempt, it helps people answer and prove you've at least produced some effort and aren't merely asking others to do your work.

Comment: @AndreaBevilacqua Do you map the results of a SQL query? If yes, this type of grouping could be permormed as part of the query.

Comment: @sn42, not only they can, they *should* be performed as part of a query.

Comment: @sn42 yes it is a result of a SQL query...I'm using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, but is very complex to group with Hibernate, because it does not support the keyword "group_concat"

Comment: If you are working with RDBMS specific operators, use [native SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql). Or you could write a DB level function and select that. If it has to be in Java, another question could be whether you must use Streams if you're not familiar with them? Though more verbose in code, you could just write the equivalent in a couple of for loops...

Answer (score 0):

you simply can make a new method that checks if the list contains the object you want to add ( compare by id), if contains then just update the string ,else add the new object to the list :

```
//add obj to list
public void add(MyObjectDTO  obj, ArrayList<MyObjectDTO> list){

    MyObjectDTO objectFromList = getObject(obj,list);

    //not contains
    if(objectFromList == null)
        list.add(obj);
    else //contains
        objectFromList.setProperty(objectFromList.getProperty + ", "+obj.getProperty());

}

public MyObjectDTO getObject(MyObjectDTO  instance,ArrayList<MyObjectDTO> list){
    for(MyObjectDTO obj:list)
        if(obj.equals(instance))
            return obj;

    return null;
}
```

you just need to override the equals method on MyObjectDTO class